# Error wire transfer into intermediary bank

Tags: canada, wire-transfer

I want to know how many days does it take for a cancelled wire transfer to be  reversed into my account.

Comment: This seems very unclear.  Are you asking about a wire transfer you initiated and now wish to reverse, or has a wire transfer been sent to you and you're wondering about it being reversed (and the money disappearing)?  It also sounds suspiciously like the lead-in to a "have I been scammed" question.  If that's where you're going, you might want to re-focus the question on the actual issue.

Comment: I sent a wire transfer to an intermediary bank, and i ask my bank to cancel the transfer, just wanna know how long will the money come into my account

Comment: Which party are you? The scammer or the target of the scam? Knowing this will allow us to help you better.

Comment: It is not a scam, just an error made, and i want the money reversed

Comment: Seems like your bank is in the best position to answer this.